# How to decrypt a simpleXor Base64encoded string

Tags: vb.net, encryption, base64, password-encryption

I am new with this encryption stuff and also i am looking into a pervious engineers code.  The encrypt works find but i would like a decryptor, i am not sure what or how to start

There is a PasswordEncryption class which looks as below

```
Public Class PasswordEncryption
    Public Shared arrBase64EncMap(64) As String
    Public Shared arrBase64DecMap(127) As Integer

    Const BASE_64_MAP_INIT As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"

    Public Shared Function EncryptionPassword() As String
        Return "F2oWrB4sA3feEh1tz"
    End Function

    Public Shared Function simpleXor(ByVal strIn As String, ByVal strKey As String) As String
        Dim iInIndex As Integer
        Dim iKeyIndex As Integer
        Dim strReturn As String
        If Len(strIn) = 0 Or Len(strKey) = 0 Then
            simpleXor = ""
            Exit Function
        End If

        iInIndex = 1
        iKeyIndex = 1
        strReturn = ""

        '** Step through the plain text source XORing the character at each point with the next character in the key **
        '** Loop through the key characters as necessary **
        Do While iInIndex <= Len(strIn)
            strReturn = strReturn & Chr(Asc(Mid(strIn, iInIndex, 1)) Xor Asc(Mid(strKey, iKeyIndex, 1)))
            iInIndex = iInIndex + 1
            If iKeyIndex = Len(strKey) Then iKeyIndex = 0
            iKeyIndex = iKeyIndex + 1
        Loop

        simpleXor = strReturn
    End Function

    Public Shared Function base64Encode(ByVal strPlain As String) As String
        Dim iLoop As Integer
        Dim iBy3 As Integer
        Dim strReturn As String
        Dim iIndex As Integer
        Dim iFirst As Integer
        Dim iSecond As Integer
        Dim iiThird As Integer

        If strPlain.Length = 0 Then
            base64Encode = ""
            Exit Function
        End If

        '** Set up Base64 Encoding and Decoding Maps for when we need them ** 
        For iLoop = 0 To Len(BASE_64_MAP_INIT) - 1
            arrBase64EncMap(iLoop) = Mid(BASE_64_MAP_INIT, iLoop + 1, 1)
        Next
        For iLoop = 0 To Len(BASE_64_MAP_INIT) - 1
            arrBase64DecMap(Asc(arrBase64EncMap(iLoop))) = iLoop
        Next

        '** Work out rounded down multiple of 3 bytes length for the unencoded text **
        iBy3 = (strPlain.Length \ 3) * 3
        strReturn = ""

        '** For each 3x8 byte chars, covert them to 4x6 byte representations in the Base64 map **
        iIndex = 1
        Do While iIndex <= iBy3
            iFirst = Asc(Mid(strPlain, iIndex + 0, 1))
            iSecond = Asc(Mid(strPlain, iIndex + 1, 1))
            iiThird = Asc(Mid(strPlain, iIndex + 2, 1))
            strReturn = strReturn & arrBase64EncMap((iFirst \ 4) And 63)
            strReturn = strReturn & arrBase64EncMap(((iFirst * 16) And 48) + ((iSecond \ 16) And 15))
            strReturn = strReturn & arrBase64EncMap(((iSecond * 4) And 60) + ((iiThird \ 64) And 3))
            strReturn = strReturn & arrBase64EncMap(iiThird And 63)
            iIndex = iIndex + 3
        Loop

        '** Handle any trailing characters not in groups of 3 **
        '** Extend to multiple of 3 characters using = signs as per RFC **
        If iBy3 < strPlain.Length Then
            iFirst = Asc(Mid(strPlain, iIndex + 0, 1))
            strReturn = strReturn & arrBase64EncMap((iFirst \ 4) And 63)
            If (strPlain.Length Mod 3) = 2 Then
                iSecond = Asc(Mid(strPlain, iIndex + 1, 1))
                strReturn = strReturn & arrBase64EncMap(((iFirst * 16) And 48) + ((iSecond \ 16) And 15))
                strReturn = strReturn & arrBase64EncMap((iSecond * 4) And 60)
            Else
                strReturn = strReturn & arrBase64EncMap((iFirst * 16) And 48)
                strReturn = strReturn & "="
            End If
            strReturn = strReturn & "="
        End If

        '** Return the encoded result string **
        base64Encode = strReturn
    End Function

End Class
```

I have a simple form which has two buttons Encrypt and Decrypt and couple of textboxes.

The click event of the encrypt button does the following

```
 Private Sub btnEncrypt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEncrypt.Click
        If tbxPassword.Text IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim PasswordEncryption As PasswordEncryption = New PasswordEncryption()
            Dim strXOR As String = PasswordEncryption.simpleXor(Strings.Left(tbxPassword.Text.ToString().Trim, 20), PasswordEncryption.EncryptionPassword)
            Dim encryptedPassword = PasswordEncryption.base64Encode(strXOR)
            tbxResult.Text = encryptedPassword
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("No action can be performed")
        End If

    End Sub
```

I have the following code in the decrypt button but it does not bring my original string back

```
Private Sub btnDecrypt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDecrypt.Click


        If tbxPassword.Text IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim PasswordEncryption As PasswordEncryption = New PasswordEncryption()
            Dim strXOR As String = PasswordEncryption.simpleXor(Strings.Left(tbxPassword.Text.ToString().Trim, 20), PasswordEncryption.EncryptionPassword)
            Dim decryptedPassword = PasswordEncryption.base64Encode(strXOR)
            tbxResult.Text = decryptedPassword
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("No action can be performed")
        End If
```

What is that i need to implement to get the original string back. Thank you guys!

Comment: In the "Decrypt" routine, you would not use base64Encode.  Instead you need to first base64Decode, then Xor that result to return the original.  You are missing a base64Decode routine (at least it's missing in the posted code).

Comment: Hi Thanks for looking into this. The current code does not have a decode method, this is what i need help with. Thank you.

Comment: Couple of additional notes - this Xor scheme is most definitely not "encryption".  Do not use this for any kind of actual real world data and interfacing. Also - the .Net Framework includes Base64 encoding and decoding methods; you do not need to roll your own, for instance this converts a byte array to a base64 string: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=netframework-4.7.2.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys i have figured it out from the following link

https://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-28425.html

I have included the decode method and as per comment from MarkL I have first Base64Decoded the string and then performed simpleXOR and i got the original string back.

My decrypt method looks like this

```
 Private Sub btnDecrypt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDecrypt.Click


        If tbxPassword.Text IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim PasswordEncryption As PasswordEncryption = New PasswordEncryption()
            ' Dim strXOR As String = PasswordEncryption.simpleXor(Strings.Left(tbxPassword.Text.ToString().Trim, 20), PasswordEncryption.EncryptionPassword)
            Dim base64DecodedValue = PasswordEncryption.base64Decode(tbxPassword.Text)

            tbxResult.Text = PasswordEncryption.simpleXor(Strings.Left(base64DecodedValue.Trim, 20), PasswordEncryption.EncryptionPassword)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("No action can be performed")
        End If

    End Sub
```